# How to concatenate an indefinite amount of lists item-wise in python

Tags: python, list, concatenation

If I have an **indefinite** amount of lists and I want to write a method for them to concatenate item-wise, what would be the best way to do this?
Meaning, I don't have just 2 lists, like list A and list B and can write something like

```
X = [x+y for x, y in zip(A, B)]
```

but I will have various lists generated, which must be sequentially concatenated, so I don't know how to iterate over a n number of lists and concatenate them.

The first list will always have 1 or more elements (**its length can be different**), and the ones after it will always have only 1 element:

```
['a','b','c'],['foo'], ['bar']....
```

The result I need is

```
['afoobar','bfoobar','cfoobar']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your indefinite amount of lists into a single list. Take the `itertools.product` and `str.join` the results.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> lists = [['a','b','c'],['foo'], ['bar']]
>>> [''.join(x) for x in product(*lists)]
['afoobar', 'bfoobar', 'cfoobar']
```

(The asterisk in `product(*lists)` is unpacking the lists again for the call to `product`, which handles an arbitrary amount of iterables)

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful!

Answer (score 4):

```
from itertools import product

[''.join(prod) for prod in product(['a','b','c'],['foo'], ['bar'])]

# ['afoobar', 'bfoobar', 'cfoobar']
```

This will work for any number of lists of any length:

```
[''.join(prod) for prod in product(['a','b','c'],
                                   ['foo1_', 'foo2_'],
                                   ['bar'], ['end'])]
# ['afoo1_barend',
#  'afoo2_barend',
#  'bfoo1_barend',
#  'bfoo2_barend',
#  'cfoo1_barend',
#  'cfoo2_barend']
```